# python3: ~2 = -0b11?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Run the following in python3

```
>>> print(2, bin(2), ~2, bin(~2))
> 2 0b10 -3 -0b11
```

I thought `~2` should be `0b01` or `0b101`.

Why `-0b11`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 2  = 00000010
~2  = 11111101
```

What's the value of `11111101` in two's complement?

To answer that, follow this simple algorithm:

- Flip all bits
- Add 1 to the result
- Determine the sign according to the MSB

---

```
11111101 > 00000010 > 00000011 
         ^          ^ 
       Flip       Add 1
```

Note that the most significant bit is "1", so the sign is negative.

Answer (score 1):

First lookat ~2:

```
 2 = 0b0000...10 (n leading 0s)
~2 = 0b1111...01 (n leading 1s)
```

Then analysis -0b11

most computer number representation using the two's complement notation, where:

```
A - B = A + ~B + 1
```

So -0b11 is acturally:

```
  - 0b11
= 0 - 0b11
= 0b0000...00 + 0b1111...00 + 1
= 0b1111...01
```

Comment: about `0x111...01`, do you mean `0b111...01`?